# How toiterate though the website search results using selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to iterate though pages of search results on this [website](https://my.supplychain.nhs.uk/catalogue). Here is a snippet of the HTML code they have for the paging section:
[Paging HTML:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAmW9.png)

Link that I want to use to go to the next page:

```html
<a href="/Catalogue/search?Query=mask%20respirator&amp;QueryType=All&amp;HideMaskedProducts=False&amp;WasCorrected=False&amp;Page=2&amp;PageSize=10&amp;TotalRecordCount=1537&amp;SortDescending=False&amp;CoreListRequest=BrowseAll">Next &gt;&gt;</a>
```

I was trying to do:

```
next_page_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/Catalogue/search?Query=face%20mask&QueryType=All&HideMaskedProducts=False&WasCorrected=False&Page=2&PageSize=10&TotalRecordCount=932&SortDescending=False&CoreListRequest=BrowseAll'")))      
next_page_link.click()
```

but it doesn't seem to work. When I print out next_page_link, it does return an element, so I think the code itself if alright. Is it something wrong with the link? Can I use it the way I am trying to or is there any other way I can iterate thought the result pages?
Thank you!

Comment: Try change your xpath expression to this `//div[contains(@class,"paging_control")]/a[contains(text(), "Next >>")]`

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH is probably causing the issue here, so the click is not going to the correct element.

Try something like this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a/text()[contains(.,"Next")]/parent::*'))).click()
```

If you want to assign it to the variable and the call the click you can also do it:

```
next_page_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a/text()[contains(.,"Next")]/parent::*')))

next_page_link.click()
```